# How to get the row value and column value(date)together of a cell in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, list, date, pivot-table

I have an excel pivot table of format:

```
    Names 2/1/2010 3/1/2010 4/1/2010
    A       8                  
    B       4          5       7
    C       5          3
    D       6          6
```

I need to get the names and date of the cells which are empty. How can I do it?
I want the output as a list: `[A:3/1/2010,4/1/2010]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming format is same as above, Check this code snippet, you can use different python module to read excel sheet

```
import xlrd
def get_list_vals() :
    res = []
    path="C:/File_PATH.xlsx"
    wb=xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet=wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    # Get rows from 2nd line
    for row in range(1, sheet.nrows) :
        temp = []
        for column in range (sheet.ncols) :
            val = sheet.cell_value(row,column)
            # get first column values like(A, B, C)
            if column == 0:
                temp.append(val)
                continue
            # if not first column, get the date data from row = 1
            elif val=="" :
                date_val = sheet.cell_value(0,column)
                temp.append(date_val)
        res.append(temp)
    return res
```

If you want specific format like [A : date1, date2] for thhis instead of temp = [] , you can append to string value

temp = []   -->> temp = ""

temp.append(val)   -->  temp += str(val) + ":"

temp.append(date_val)  -->> temp + str(val) + ","